# Find subsets of data that are related in a large, sparse dataset

Tags: data-analysis

I have a dataset with a big number of features (it is coming from a document-oriented database). 80% of the features are 80% empty and filled in only in specific conditions. Let me give an example with an animals dataset :

- *Number_of_paws* is filled for every animal where living_place = ground,
- *Coat_color* is filled for every animal where aspect = coat,
- *Depth_in_water* is filled only for fishs, ...

How can I determine, for a new unknown feature to what subset of data it is related? So imagine a feature *%something_unknown* that is empty 98% of the time and I want to discover that this feature is only filled in when *Animal_color = Red* and *Animal_type = fish*.

I would say that it is related to subset analysis. How should one proceed to solve this problem ?

Comment: one can do the inverse procedure to determine complementary features from features. For example: feature `number_of_paws` has co-feature the `living_place=ground` and so on. Then once you have a map of features to co-features you can do the inverse process

Answer (score 0):

A contingency table might be useful. It displays the multivariate frequency distribution of categorical variables.